# Functional Analysis (Topological and Isometric Isomorphisms)

Tags: functional-analysis

Give an example that if two normed linear spaces are topologically isomorphic then they need not be isometrically isomorphic.  I searched my book and on the Internet but in vain.

Comment: I think the OP meant *linearly isomorphic*. However, David's example works, of course. To see that $c$ and $c_0$ are not isometric one could observe that the unit ball of $c$ has extreme points but that of $c_0$ does not.

Answer (score 2):

Any two non-isometric finite dimensional normed spaces having the same dimension would do the job. For instance take $\mathbb{R}^d$ endowed with two $\ell_p$-norms for different $p\geqslant 1$.

The notion of the [Banach–Mazur compactum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Mazur_compactum) might be of interest to you.

Answer (score 1):

Denote $X=C(K)$, $Y=C(L)$ where $K$ and $L$ are Hausdorff locally compact topological spaces.

Then by [Banach-Stone theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Stone_theorem) $X$ and $Y$ are isometric iff $K$ and $L$ are homeomorphic.

If $K$ and $L$ are both uncountable, then by Miljutin theorem $X$ and $Y$ are isomorphic.

Thus there is an abundance of examples: take any two uncountable topological spaces that are not homeomorphic and you get the desired example. Say $K=[0,1]$, $L=[0,1]\cup\{2\}$.